# php mail function error on windows hosting

Tags: php, email

Mail function now not working my server. i cannot find out the solution for that. i am getting bellow this error when i submitting the contact form.

> Warning: `mail()` [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 550 Sender is not allowed. in E:\HostingSpace\abayamtranslations.com\httpdocs\contact-form\classes\contact.php on line 137
>   ERROR! Please ensure PHP `Mail()` is correctly configured on this server.

```
$address = "info@abayamtranslations.com";

ini_set("SMTP","mail.abayamtranslations.com");
ini_set("smtp_port","25");
ini_set('sendmail_from','info@abayamtranslations.com');
$headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 0):

"550 Sender is not allowed" means that the SMTP Blocked Senders list rejected the sender. Search your SMTP log for 550 Sender is not allowed and figure out what address is getting blocked and then alter your list to let that through.

That is the meaning of the error you are getting. This is from the [hMailServer Documentation](http://www.hmailserver.com/documentation/latest/?page=reference_error_messages_smtp).

Can you try if the following will work?

```
<?php
mail('info@abayamtranslations.com','Test Email','This is a test email.',"From: info@abayamtranslations.com");
?>
```

If it doesn't work, then it's probably due to a misconfiguration in your hMailServer and you would need to check your [hMailServer Logs](http://www.hmailserver.com/documentation/latest/?page=reference_logging).

Answer (score 0):

Try with the following

```
$emailFrom = "info@abayamtranslations.com"; // match this to the domain you are sending email from
$email = "example@example.com";
$subject = "Subject of email";
$headers = 'From:' . $emailFrom . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . $email . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Return-path: " . $email;
$message = "Message of email";
mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are on the windows server, hence forth you have to change SMTP of windows server.

Better way is to use PHPMailer Library. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Answer (score 0):

Some important information is missing under your SMTP configuration....
**username and password** is needed to authenticate with the SMTP mail server.....
it easy ti use smtp mailing in php with:

**PHPMailer**  (https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailerhttps://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer)

have a look into it....

Thankyou....